# No canonical correspondance between bilinear forms $b:V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and linear forms $\hat{b}:V\otimes V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: tensor-products, bilinear-form, universal-property

In the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form#Relation_to_tensor_products) on bilinear forms, the universal product says that to each bilnear map $b : V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we can associate a linear map $\hat{b} : V\otimes V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, namely $\hat{b}(v\otimes w)=b(v,w)$. But they claim that this association is not canonical. I don't understand why, since this seems like the obvious choice for the correspondence, no?

Comment: The WP is wrong here, at least on the "canonical" part. As for "unique": sure, you can twist it by automorphisms, but the definition isn't to blame for that.

Comment: I fixed the Wikipedia article.